# How to prove the child node' s formular of heap: node i-th have 2 child are 2i-th and 2i+1-th?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, heap

It is easy to see that the formular is right, but I don't know how to prove this. How about some other trees such as : the tree which each node have 3 child, 4 child... ? 
Thanks!

Comment: Try proof by induction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must prove that, if you traverse a full binary tree in level-order, you'll always visit the children of the node you visited in the `n`th time at the `2n`th and `2n+1`th times.

We can do this by induction. Proving the base case is trivial:

```
   1
 /   \
2     3
```

Now, we must prove that if it's true for some `n`, it is also true for `n+1`:

If you we visit the children of `n` in `2n` and `2n+1` time, the children of `n+1` will be right next to them, being visited in times `2n+2 = 2(n+1)` and `2n+3 = 2(n+1)+1`.

Q.E.D.

```
          .
          .
          .

    n          n+1
  /   \       /   \
2n   2n+1  2n+2   2n+3
```

The image is just an example, `n` and `n+1` may lie in different levels. This is no problem. The children of `n` and `n+1` will always be neighbors because the way the level-order is implemented (visiting the node and adding the children to a queue).

Answer (score -2):

It's more like a definition than a proof: you define it to be that way and then you work with it while making sure you remain within the bounds of the invariant you defined. You might want to prove that there is no overlap, but that is rather easy to see.

For 3 children, we can use `3i, 3i+1, 3i+2`:

```
          1
        / | \
       2  3  4 --
             | \  \
             5  6  7

index: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 
label: - - 2 3 4 - - - - -  -  5  6  7
```

However, as you can see, this gets rather inefficient. It will probably be faster than using pointers if you can afford the memory, but otherwise it won't be of much use.

Comment: It is a two way theorem. 1. Prove in a k-ary if we define the array representation as each node's children are stored at index k*n through k*(n+1)-1 then this is the same as storing level by level and each level right to its upper level. 2. Prove that when we define the array representation as each level right to its upper level then each node's children are stored at k*n to k*(n+1)-1.